# Projection brings in duplicate data on DAC

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to create a Projection that will join the FSSODet file with the FSAppointmentDet file for use in a process screen.

This is the SQL I am trying to reproduce:

```
SELECT FD.[SrvOrdType] ,FD.[RefNbr]
      ,FD.[OrigSrvOrdNbr],FD.[OrigLineNbr]
      ,FD.[UnitCost],FD.[UnitPrice]
      ,FS.[RefNbr] ,FS.[LineNbr]
      ,FS.[LineRef],FS.[UnitCost]
      ,FS.[UnitPrice],FS.[TranDesc]
      ,FS.[SODetID],FS.[SOID]
From [FSAppointmentDet] FD
   JOIN [FSSODet] FS on FD.OrigSrvOrdNbr = FS.RefNbr 
   AND FS.LineNbr = FD.OrigLineNbr
WHERE fs.UnitPrice <> FD.UnitPrice
```

This is what I have:

```
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<FSAppointmentDet,
    InnerJoin<FSSODet,
    On<FSSODet.refNbr, Equal<FSAppointmentDet.origSrvOrdNbr>,
       And<FSSODet.lineNbr, Equal<FSAppointmentDet.origLineNbr>>>>,
    Where<FSSODet.unitPrice, NotEqual<FSAppointmentDet.unitPrice>>>), Persistent = true)]
[PXCacheName("FixPriceProjection")]
public class PlyFixPriceProjDAC : IBqlTable
{
    #region Selected
    public abstract class selected : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<selected> { }
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Composite Key
    public class PK : PrimaryKeyOf<PlyFixPriceProjDAC>.By<origSrvOrdNbr, origLineNbr>
    {
        public static PlyFixPriceProjDAC Find(PXGraph graph, string origSrvOrdNbr, int? origLineNbr)
            => FindBy(graph, origSrvOrdNbr, origLineNbr);
    }
    #endregion

    #region From the FSAppointmentDet DAC
    #region FDRefNbr
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.refNbr))]
    public virtual string FDRefNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class fDRefNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<fDRefNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region OrigSrvOrdNbr
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.origSrvOrdNbr))]
    public virtual string OrigSrvOrdNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class origSrvOrdNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<origSrvOrdNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region OrigLineNbr
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.origLineNbr))]
    public virtual int? OrigLineNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class origLineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<origLineNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region FDUnitCost
    [PXDBDecimal(4, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.unitCost))]
    public virtual decimal? FDUnitCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class fDUnitCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<fDUnitCost> { }
    #endregion

    #region FDUnitPrice
    [PXDBDecimal(4, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.unitPrice))]
    public virtual decimal? FDUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public abstract class fDUnitPrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<fDUnitPrice> { }
    #endregion


    #region InventoryID
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }

    [StockItem(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.inventoryID), Enabled = false)]
    public virtual Int32? InventoryID { get; set; }
    #endregion



    #endregion

    #region From the FSSODet DAC
    #region FSRefNbr
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.refNbr))]
    public virtual string FSRefNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSRefNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<fSRefNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region FSLineNbr
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.lineNbr))]
    public virtual int? FSLineNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSLineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<fSLineNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region FSLineRef
    [PXDBString(30, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.lineRef))]
    public virtual string FSLineRef { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSLineRef : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<fSLineRef> { }
    #endregion

    #region FSUnitCost
    [PXDBDecimal(4, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.unitCost))]
    public virtual decimal? FSUnitCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSUnitCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<fSUnitCost> { }
    #endregion

    #region FSUnitPrice
    [PXDBDecimal(4, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.unitPrice))]
    public virtual decimal? FSUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSUnitPrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<fSUnitPrice> { }
    #endregion

    #region TranDesc
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.tranDesc))]
    public virtual string TranDesc { get; set; }
    public abstract class tranDesc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<tranDesc> { }
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

When I run this, it selects 1535 records, which is correct. But all of the records has the same data.

[image: data screen]

I put this in my graph code to check it and I see that the count is right, but the data is not.

```
            public PXProcessing<PlyFixPriceProjDAC> Processing;

var Items = Processing.Select();
    var totRecords =  Items.Count;
    foreach (PlyFixPriceProjDAC item in Items)
    {
        var so = item.OrigSrvOrdNbr;
    }
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you have defined IsKey=True on some dac fields, that wierdness is due to the grid not having a key defined