# Row Data Blanking on Select; Projection DAC not retrieving anything but Keys - Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

This is a follow-up to this case.[Projection brings in duplicate data on DAC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77917112/628887) I spun it off since it is dealing with a separate issue surrounding the same use case.

My issue is in my projection DAC, I define a DAC which combines FSAppointmentDet and FSSODet.

I added keys to SrvOrdType, LineNbr, and RefNbr (based on the PK of FSAppointmentDet) so it can display the info correctly.

The Process Screen loads up and displays the records fine.
[image: Process Screen Display]

But as soon as I Select a row, the data on the Row is blanked out (except for the Line Nbr Column)

[image: After Select]

When I look at the code, and set breakpoints, I see that when the process routine is run the only values in the Item (based on the DAC) are the fields I have specified as a key.

What am I missing here?

This is my DAC:

```
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<FSAppointmentDet,
    InnerJoin<FSSODet,
    On<FSSODet.refNbr, Equal<FSAppointmentDet.origSrvOrdNbr>,
       And<FSSODet.lineNbr, Equal<FSAppointmentDet.origLineNbr>>>>,
    Where<FSSODet.unitPrice, NotEqual<FSAppointmentDet.unitPrice>>>), Persistent = true)]
[PXCacheName("FixPriceProjection")]
public class PriceProjDAC : IBqlTable
{
    #region Selected
    public abstract class selected : IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected bool? _Selected = false;
    [PXBool]
    [PXDefault(false, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public virtual bool? Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _Selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _Selected = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion       

    #region From the FSAppointmentDet DAC

    #region SrvOrdType
    public abstract class srvOrdType : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<srvOrdType> { }
    [PXDBString(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.srvOrdType))]
    public virtual string SrvOrdType { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region LineNbr
    public abstract class lineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<lineNbr> { }
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.lineNbr))]
    public virtual int? LineNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region RefNbr
    public abstract class refNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<refNbr> { }
    [PXDBString(IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.refNbr))]
    public virtual string RefNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region OrigSrvOrdNbr
    public abstract class origSrvOrdNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<origSrvOrdNbr> { }
    [PXDBString(BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.origSrvOrdNbr))]
    public virtual string OrigSrvOrdNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region FDUnitPrice
    [PXDBDecimal(4, BqlField = typeof(FSAppointmentDet.unitPrice))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Appt Price")]
    public virtual decimal? FDUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public abstract class fDUnitPrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<fDUnitPrice> { }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region From the FSSODet DAC
    #region FSRefNbr
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.refNbr))]
    public virtual string FSRefNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSRefNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<fSRefNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region FSLineNbr
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.lineNbr))]
    public virtual int? FSLineNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSLineNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<fSLineNbr> { }
    #endregion

    #region FSUnitPrice
    [PXDBDecimal(4, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.unitPrice))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "SO Price")]
    public virtual decimal? FSUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public abstract class fSUnitPrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<fSUnitPrice> { }
    #endregion

    #region TranDesc
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(FSSODet.tranDesc))]
    public virtual string TranDesc { get; set; }
    public abstract class tranDesc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<tranDesc> { }
    #endregion
    #endregion
}
```

And this is the Process Screen Graph (in case it is needed)

```
public class PSFixPrice : PXGraph<PSFixPrice>
{
    // Define the processing view which will select all   
    // correct records baswd on the definition in the projection
     public PXProcessing<PriceProjDAC> Processing;


    public PSFixPrice()
    {
        var tst = new PriceProjDAC();
        int i = 0;
        // Acuminator disable once PX1008 LongOperationDelegateSynchronousExecution [Justification]
        Processing.SetProcessDelegate(
                delegate (List<PriceProjDAC> list)
                {
                    DoLogic(list, Processing.Cache);
                });
    }
    static public void DoLogic(IList records, PXCache onCache)
    {
        var onGraph = onCache.Graph;
        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(onGraph, delegate ()
        {
            var cacheName = onCache.GetName();
            using (PXTransactionScope FSSODETScope = new PXTransactionScope())
            {
                foreach (var item in records ) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PriceProjDAC projDAC = item as PriceProjDAC;
                        if (projDAC != null) 
                        {
                            ProcessItem(projDAC, onCache);
                        }
                    } catch { }
                }
                // Save all changes after processing all items
                // onGraph.Actions.PressSave();
                FSSODETScope.Complete();

            } // End PXTransactionScope
        }); // PXLongOperation end brace
    }  // doLogic end brace
    // Define the processing logic for each item
    static private void ProcessItem(PriceProjDAC item, PXCache onCache)
    {

        if (item.Selected == true)
        {
            // Update the FSSODet UnitPrice with FSAppointmentDet UnitPrice
      //      item.FSUnitPrice = item.FDUnitPrice;

            // Update the record in the cache
      //      onCache.Update(item);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the ASPX (although it has changed slightly since I posted this question. I made some changes to the data source name, but the rest should be the same)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="PS305020.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_PS305020" Title="SO Price Fix Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="ASGFix.PSFixPrice"
        PrimaryView="Processing"
        >
        <CallbackCommands>

        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
    <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Primary" 
    AdjustPageSize="Auto" AllowPaging="True" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Processing">
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" Type="CheckBox" Width="60" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="OrigSrvOrdNbr" Width="150" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LineNbr" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" Width="75" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="FDUnitPrice" Width="75" ></px:PXGridColumn>                                     
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="FSUnitPrice" Width="75" ></px:PXGridColumn>                                     
                </Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
        <ActionBar >
        </ActionBar>
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you add your aspx as well?

Comment: @JoshuaVanHoesen : I added it. (See above) I changed the name of the datasource in this because I spun it out into a new customization, but the structure and field names are the same. BTW, I was able to get a workaround by declaring each field with IsKey=True -- but even then there were a couple of fields that wouldn't work, so I just eliminated them from the screen. Very frustrating!)